# "ghost" commit message when using a staging branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, branching-and-merging, pull-request

So, in a repo my group uses daily, we have the following flow:

(staging is the "default" branch)

```
feature branch(es) -> PR-> staging branch -> PR -> production branch
```

The idea is that staging is the place where many of the feature branches are combined, and a "release" is done to production.

However, when we open the PR to production, we almost always see many many "old" (already merged into production) commit messages. The diff on the file level always looks good, with just the changes from staging, but the commit message history is always way off.

What are we missing? Someone not branching off of an updated staging? Should we be rebasing staging from production after a merge? Or merging production unto staging to pick up the merge commit?

If it matters, we typically squash at merge time into staging, in an effort to keep the history on staging/production clean/simple.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please give a specific example of the behavior you are seeing and how it differs from the behavior you are expecting.  You may want to consult the Help Center for [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of tricky to catch your problem, but your flow IMO is not really a good practice, because you will have to always make sure that the commit history between staging and production is the same.

What is happening is that the diffs are good because there is nothing wrong actually, but git doesn't care about that, it cares about your commit history. and that seems to be messed up, and its hard to know the reason right away without looking at your repo. however, the easy way to fix this is to always merge production unto staging.

the better way to do this, is to make sure you have the same commit history (i.e. the production does not have extra old commit that threw off the commit history) you can do this by simply visualizing your repo. you can use a 3rd party tool, or just run

```
git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
```

if your staging and production branches off long time ago and never meet, then you have a problem. and then you need to sync these branches, probably by rebasing one into another but that could introduce a lot of conflicts, so you might want to start a new production branch off of the staging and use this one instead and make sure you have same commit history afterwards.